# Escape Characters in VM Option in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables, jvm

I want to pass a VM argument in eclipse which is dependent on an environment variable.Something like this -

In Environment variables:
var1=1234

In VM arguments:
-Dvar2=%var1%5678

This works properly without any issue using terminal but doesn't work in Eclipse

Eclipse encodes this '%' sign to '25', hence compiler is not able to find the value of 'var1' variable in 'var2'.
Can anyone suggest on how to escape this '%' symbol or any other workaround.

Comment: In the launch configuration, in VM arguments a variable has to be used as follows: `-Dvar2=${env_var:var1}5678`. Use _Show Command Line_ button to verify whether it is correctly resolved.

Comment: `System.getProperty("var2")` should return `12345678`, not `%var1%5678`, right? If yes, see my answer below. Otherwise, please tell what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In the launch configuration, in the ***VM arguments*** field use the **`env_var` variable** for a value of an environment variable as follows:

```
-Dvar2=${env_var:var1}5678
```

Use the button *Variables...* at the bottom of the *VM arguments* field to get a dialog that assists you in entering variables.

Please note, the `env_var` variable can only be used for environment variables that are visible in the process in which Eclipse is running.

Answer (score 0):

In the launch configuration,

1. select the button 'Variables' below the VM arguments field.
2. On the Select Variables dialog, select 'env_var' from the list of variables. Enter Argument as 'var1'. Click 'Ok'
3. Now the VM argument will have format as ${env_var:var1} and edit it to have the format '-Dvar2=${env_var:var1}5678'